# C# Textbox in MDI Child Form - Strange Behaviour

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I've got this strange issue I've never encountered before. I've done a bunch of searching online and have found people with the same issue, but no proper fixes (at least none that I can find).

Basically, I have a C# WinForm application launches child forms and adds them to the controls of the main form (so rather than the child forms launching as a separate window, they launch within the main application window).

The strange behaviour is that any TextBox controls on the child forms don't accept any mouse input. If I try to click in the TextBox to put the cursor at a specific point in the text, the cursor always goes to the first character. I can move around using the keyboard, but not with the mouse.

I have set the main form as an MDI Container (this.IsMdiContainer = true) and have also set the parameters of the child form correctly:

```
childForm.TopLevel = false;
childForm.AutoScroll = true;
childform.Parent = parentForm;
parentForm.Controls.Add(childForm);
```

I initially had the childForm loading inside a panel, but removed the panel as there's no IsMdiContainer parameter for a panel control, but loading it inside the main form doesn't seem to work either. Weird, man. Weird.

Any hints?

Comment: `and have also set the parameters of the child form correctly:`  If childForm is an mdi child, you have to set the childForm.MdiParent property.  MDI child forms require a normal sizable border, too.

Comment: Thanks mate. We always miss the little things, huh? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its *not Parent*, **its MDIParent**:

```
childForm.MdiParent = this; //(or parentForm)
```

Comment: If I make that change, I end up with an exception that reads:
'Form cannot be added to the Controls collection that has a valid MDI parent'

Comment: Ok, I removed the this.Controls.Add(childForm) and now it works. I suppose once I set the MdiParent parameter, the childForm no longer needs to be added manually to the parentForm control collection?